# Выборка уникальных идентификаторов из трех таблиц + исключение

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Ребят, привет!

В процессе обучения поставил целью решить сложную задачку, но она мне оказалась не под силу. 
Как корректно составить выборку при помощи JOIN оператора?

Суть задачи: 
Допустим, есть 3 таблицы:

1. |id|num_id|param|
2. |num_id|param|
3. |num_id|param|

Условие:
Нужно выбрать все записи id, кроме тех, у которых в 3-й таблице в колонке param присутствует значение true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table_1.id FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_3 USING(num_id)
WHERE table_3.param <> 1
```

Comment: @oscar2000, забыл спросить: а в третьей таблицы есть только одна запись с данным num_id?

Т.е. в ней не может быть строк (1, 1), (1, 2)? Я исходил из этого (т.е. двух num_id быть не может), поэтому запрос в таком виде.

Если в таблице может быть несколько строк с одним num_id, тогда один и тот же id из первой таблицы будет выведен несколько раз. Чтобы избежать этого достаточно добавить `DISTINCT` в запрос.

Comment: Про USING спасибо. А если нужно связать все 3 таблицы по num_id?

Comment: @oscar2000, делаем аналогично table_3. Вот [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf81/3)

Comment: Усложню задачку. А вдруг во 2ой таблице имя не num_id, а просто id, но связь должна быть по num_id?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, это как-то странно выглядит - как у num_id может быть одновременно два значения? Разве что num_id является массивом значений, либо  дополнительно есть еще какие-то поля (например, дата), по которым можно группировать.

Но тогда надо уточнить какой именно вывод ожидается. Приведите примеры исходных данных и ожидаемый вывод, тогда будет ясно что именно вам хочется. Вот вам [примеры](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a86/5) различного вывода (возможных вариантов больше)

А если будет id, то вместо `USING` делаем `ON table_1.num_id = table_2.id`

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, пошел изучать :). Попробую потом показать на каком-нибудь примере.